# How to add background image from local folder to a container

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, jsx

I want to set the background image of a container div from an image from a local folder. Does anyone know what i need to add to my code/ how to edit it to do this? Currently the image isnt showing for some reason.

```
class Team extends React.Component{


    render(){

        let style = {
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundImage:'url("../images/Football_Field.png")',
            backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            border: '2px dashed #333'
        }

        return (
            <div className="container" style={style}>

                <i className="fas fa-tshirt"></i>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Team
```

The image is in a 'image' folder inside the src folder. (/src/images/Football_Field.png)

The `Team` components file path is '/src/components/Team'.

Would anyone also know how to do this if i instead used a ui container class?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like it in your render method :)
Do Know that the path is rooted at the public folder once it's compiled

```js
     render()
    {
        const image = './images/tasse_kandinsky.webp';
        return(
            <div className='product'>
      
                <div className='product-image' style={{backgroundImage: 'url('+image+')'}}>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your webpack configuration, you could do something like this:

```
import backgroundImage from "../images/Football_Field.png";

class Team extends React.Component{
    render(){

        let style = {
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundImage:'url(' + backgroundImage + ')',
            backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            border: '2px dashed #333'
        }

        return (
            <div className="container" style={style}>

                <i className="fas fa-tshirt"></i>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Team
```

Otherwise add your image to your public folder and change the url accordingly.

Comment: why do you use the two + operators either side of `backgroundImage` inside url()?

Comment: @Sean It is just a string concatenation. Some webpack configurations allow you to import an image in your js file. At build time the imported image will be copied in the build folder along with the rest and its value in the javascript files replaced by the relative path of the file. So in the above example, the variable `backgroundImage` will be set to a string with the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps -> 
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

All you need is a static folder to serve assets, and if you used create-react-app, you just need to put your images in the public folder and follow the doc above.